# "Bundle Identifier differs from prior bundle identifier" Error while uploading .app of New Version of iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am getting this error"Bundle Identifier differs from prior bundle identifier" while uploading the .app file for the next version of my iPhone App.

Note: I have revoked my old Distribution Certificate and re-generated it.

What could be the possible solution?

Thanks !!

Comment: Check the bundle identifier. I think it must be different than the one with which you deployed the previous version of your application.

Comment: Try deleting the contents of your build directory rather than just doing a clean. I had this happen to be once and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Are you looking to create a new version for Appstore application?

Comment: @Parth : Dude that's the problem. I have revoked the certificate, regenerated so bundle id is different.

Comment: @FiddleMeRagged : Let me try.. Thanks

Comment: If yes then must be require the version same as in your application info as like you mention on create a new version on itunes.Example V1.2 in your application info file same as details u mention on creating the new version for your app on itunesconnect.

Comment: @Sandy : Yes, I am uploading a new version of my app.

Comment: @FiddleMeRagged : Didn't work for me. Anyways Thanks :)

Comment: @Learner then check as i mention in my comment, is it same at both place.

Comment: @sandy : Version name and number is same everywhere. The error is about the bundle identifier. In V1.0 my bundle identifier was different and in V1.2 I have a different bundle identifier.

Comment: @Learner I think it has to match the previous bundle identifier which you had used while uploading previous version of the app. If the bundle Id is changed then it cannot update your version. As it would treat it as a different app all together.

Comment: The Provisioning profile you use to create the build for new version having the same AppId as like mention in your previous version? Plz check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a new version of your previous application the you have to check the given condition

- Must be require the version same as in your application info as like you mention on create a new version on itunes. Sample Example- V1.2 in your application info file same as details u mention on creating the new version for your app on itunesconnect.

Comment: Is it compulsory that Bundle Identifier of both versions should match or there is any other way to do it?

Comment: If Provisioning profile you use to create the build for new version not having the same AppId as like mention in your previous version, then you have to create a new Application.